# Monitor shown as 16:10 instead of 16:9

Tags: display, resolution

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon on a Dell Latitude E6540 with a Dell U2713hm monitor, the displays are not mirrored, and arranged next to each other. The monitor has an aspect ratio of 16:9, however, it is recongnized by Linux Mint as a 16:10 monitor, and I can only select 16:10 resolutions (or 4:3 resolutions). This makes everything look pretty bad. Under Windows 7, the monitor is recognized correctly, with a resolution of 1920 x 1080, under Linux Mint I only get 1920 x 1200.

This is what xrandr -- query gives me:

```
xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0 
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9 
   1600x1024      60.2 
   1400x1050      60.0 
   1280x1024      60.0 
   1440x900       59.9 
   1280x960       60.0 
   1360x768       59.8     60.0 
   1152x864       60.0 
   1024x768       60.0 
   800x600        60.3     56.2 
   640x480        59.9 
VGA2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1200      60.0*
   1600x1200      60.0 
   1680x1050      59.9 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0 
   1280x800       59.9 
   1152x864       75.0 
   1024x768       75.1     60.0 
   800x600        75.0     60.3 
   640x480        75.0     60.0 
   720x400        70.1 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-0 disconnected
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, I did realize that, but I thought that being based on Ubuntu 14.04, this issue and a potential solution would be identical for Linux Mint

Comment: Look for something like `Printing probed modes for output HDMI3` in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, immediately followed by a list of modes reported by the monitor and immediately preceded by the raw EDID block in hex. That will prove what modes the monitor hardware is actually offering. Maybe add that info into the question. I would be surprised if it differed from what `xrandr` was reporting.